# GIS Application

Tags: map

I am currently scouring the AppExchange for an App, or set of Lightning Components, that would allow me to display maps in SalesForce - the main feature I need, which I am struggling to find, is being able to use my own GIS mapping server, and feeding [SalesForce via WFS and WMS services](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80948/what-are-the-differences-between-wms-wfs-wcs-wps) - not just Google Maps.

Is there an app out there that people are using that does this, if so what is it? I have tried GeoPointe which is pretty awesome, but so far I cannot use my own maps or feeds with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/). It is the leading open-source JavaScript library for mobile-friendly interactive maps. From a GIS point of view, WMS handling in Leaflet is quite basic. But you can give it a try, here is a link describing *WMS in Leaflet*.

[WMS in Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html)

[Trailhead Link for using Leaflet in Salesforce](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/account-geolocation-app/steps/lc-app-06)